# Finding a subset cover in a special case where each element is covered by exactly two sets.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

This question is taken from the problem here: [bookcircle](https://open.kattis.com/problems/bookcircle). I'll describe the important aspects here: There are $B$ boys and $G$ girls in a book club, as well as a set of books, lets call them $b_1, ..., b_n$. Each book has been read by exactly one boy and one girl. I have to find the smallest cardinality set of club members $S$ (can be a mix of boys and girls) such that every book has been read by someone in $S$.

Under these conditions, choosing $S$ to be all the boys or all the girls will cover all books, but does not guarantee that $S$ will be minimal. A greedy solution where at each step, you try to pick the person covering the most of the uncovered books, also does not seem to work (I can't see how to tiebreak between two sets correctly).

I have been stuck on this problem for super long, but without much progress. I have a strong hunch it should be reduced to a bipartite matching kind of problem, (or maybe even a flow problem) but I am having trouble finding what the left vertex set and right vertex sets should be.

Could anyone give a hint for this problem?

Some thoughts:

If it is really a matching problem, then I would need to find a property to be maximized, so that a max matching algorithm can find it. Intuitively we would want to maximize the amount of non-overlap between the members of $S$. But maximizing the non-overlapping does not translate to minimizing number of people chosen, so this can't be the way.

We could also try to maximize the number of people not in $S$, but this does not seem like it can be converted to maximum matching.

I try to make use of the fact that each book has been read by exactly 1 boy and 1 girl, which would suggest constructing a graph with vertices the boys and girls, and an edge between a boy and girl vertex if they have both read a book in common. But again, this graph does not seem to be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to make use of the fact that each book has been read by exactly 1 boy and 1 girl, which would suggest constructing a graph with vertices the boys and girls, and an edge between a boy and girl vertex if they have both read a book in common. But again, this graph does not seem to be very useful.

On the contrary, this graph is very useful: a set $S$ of club members such that every book is read by at least one member corresponds to a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of this graph. Thus, your problem is equivalent to finding a minimum vertex cover. In general, this is NP-complete; luckily, your graph is bipartite, with classes made up by the boys and the girls, respectively. In this case, [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) asserts that the size of a minimum vertex cover is the same as the size of a maximum matching. Moreover, a minimum vertex cover can be produced efficiently from a maximum matching (see the "constructive proof" in the Wikipedia link above).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation - it is much clearer to me now. I completely forgot to try to see it in terms of a vertex cover.